# Trying to convert object to string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm trying to search a string for a  tag and I can't seem to get it to work correctly. Here is the js. The goal is to get the console to give me "this works", which is not happening.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('div').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        console.log(target);
        if (target.indexOf("<b>") > 0) {
            console.log("this works");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>This text is normal <b>this text is bold</b></div>
```

When I click inside the bold tag I get this in the console:

```
<b>this text is bold</b>
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLElement> has no method 'indexOf'
```

So I tried to convert it to a string by changing the variable to:

```
var target = String(e.target);
```

When I do that and click on the bold tag I get this:

```
[object HTMLElement]
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You need the HTML of said element:

```
var html = $(e.target).html();
if (text.indexOf("<b>")) //do stuff
```

Comment: This just gave me the text inside the bold tag, I need it to return the text with the bold tags on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You want to search the html:

```
if ($(this).html().indexOf("<b>") > -1)
```

Though I would probably take a more object-oriented approach:

```
if ($(this).find('b').length > 0) {
```

Or if you want to see if the `b` was clicked:

```
if ($(e.target).is('b')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The third line is where the problem is occurring; you just need to get the text from the element rather than the element itself:

http://jsfiddle.net/PK72y/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">This text is normal <b>this text is bold</b></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#test').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    var txt = $(e.currentTarget).html();
    if (txt.indexOf("<b>") > 0) {
        $('#output').html("this works");
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work when I click on the bold text, just the non-bold text. Not sure why thats happening.

Comment: @EthanNYC sorry about that, should have used `e.currentTarget` rather than `e.target` so it would read `html()` from `#test` rather than from any nested elements. Updated fiddle and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the tag by checking: 
if($(this).find("b").length > 0)
The detailed code is as follows:

```
$('#test').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if($(this).find("b").length > 0){
        $('#output').html("this works");
    }
});
```

The working version is shown as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/dFkeu/2/)

Comment: This works for the letter "b" but Im looking for the tag "<b>"

Comment: EthanNYC,$(this).find("b") actually means to find tag "<b>". I attach jquery API: http://api.jquery.com/find/ here for your reference.